# How to put a layer under the App Bar in Compose?

Tags: layout, android-jetpack-compose

I have two screens with a `TopAppBar`. On the first screen I need to put a map layout under this app bar: it's possible to switch the app bar's visibility. Currently I'm doing something like this to avoid the map recomposition animation lagging:

```
Scaffold{
   Box {
       if (uiVisible) TopBar()
       NavGraph() //Google Maps there
   }
```

But it's not good to the second screen where the `TopBar` should be on top with the default behavior. So, how can I set the topBar a default behavior and put a map layer "under it" without the animation lagging while switching its visibility?

```
val topBar: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = if (uiVisible) {TopBar()} else null

Scaffold(topBar = topBar){
   NavGraph()
```